# Generating a generic delay package in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm looking for the correct syntax to build a generic line delay package using generics and for loops in a process. I understand that for loops when used with generate are for concurrent statements, but surely there must be a way to build it.

For example:

```
entity Delay_Line is
    Generic (
        CLK_DELAYS : integer := 10);
    Port ( 
        CLK    : in  STD_LOGIC;
        i_Din  : in  STD_LOGIC;
        o_Q    : out  STD_LOGIC;
        o_Qnot : out  STD_LOGIC);
    end Delay_Line;

architecture Delay_Line_arch of Delay_Line is

    signal din_dly : std_logic_vector(CLK_DELAYS-1 downto 0);
begin
    din_dly(0) <= i_Din;

    process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            for index in 0 to CLK_DELAYS-1 generate
            begin
                din_dly(index+1) <= din_dly(index);
            end;
        end if;
    end process;
    o_Q        <= din_dly(CLK_DELAYS);
    o_Qnot     <= NOT (din_dly(CLK_DELAYS));

end Delay_Line_arch;
```

Typically I would just add a bunch of:

```
din_delay(9) <= din_delay(8);
din_delay(8) <= din_delay(7);
...
```

in the code, but honestly I'd like something a little more reusable as a package.

Comment: It's not clear what you want that's different from what you've posted. That being said, your current code has 1 or 2 bugs (that your compiler would tell you about)

Answer (score 3):

It isn't really necessary to use such elaborate methods to implement shift registers. You can implement them directly in one line using array concatenation and slicing.

```vhdl
constant DELAY_STAGES : positive := 10; -- Or use a generic parameter

signal delay_line : std_logic_vector(1 to DELAY_STAGES);
...

process(clk) is
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    delay_line <= i_Din & delay_line(1 to DELAY_STAGES-1); -- Shift right
  end if;
end process;

-- Retrieve the end of the delay without a hard-coded index
o_Q <= delay_line(delay_line'high);
```

The brevity of this approach pretty much eliminates any convenience of having a component that you need to instantiate with port and generic maps. Plus you have the flexibility of being able to tap off whatever intermediate signals you may need.

Answer (score 1):

To get Pablo R’s method to work with large busses and delays `bus_size := 16` and `delay := 256`. I had to change:

```
temp_bus2 <= i_bus2 & temp_bus2(delay*bus_size - 1 downto (delay-1)*bus_size);
```

to

```
temp_bus2 <= i_bus2 & temp_bus2(delay*bus_size - 1 downto (bus_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my generic_delay component:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY generic_delay is
  generic (
    bus_size    : natural;
    delay       : natural
    );
  port (
    i_Clock : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    i_reset : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    i_bus1  : in std_logic_vector(bus_size - 1 downto 0);
    i_bus2  : in std_logic_vector(bus_size - 1 downto 0);
    o_bus1  : out std_logic_vector(bus_size - 1 downto 0);
    o_bus2  : out std_logic_vector(bus_size - 1 downto 0)
    );
end generic_delay;


architecture a of generic_delay is

----------------------------
-- SIGNALS DECLARATION
----------------------------
  signal temp_bus1 : std_logic_vector(delay*bus_size - 1 downto 0);
  signal temp_bus2 : std_logic_vector(delay*bus_size - 1 downto 0);
  
BEGIN
  
-----------------------------------------
-- SYNCHRONOUS PROCESS
-----------------------------------------
  process(i_Clock, i_reset)

  begin
    
    if i_reset = '1' then
      temp_bus1 <= (others => '0');
      temp_bus2 <= (others => '0');

    elsif falling_edge(i_Clock) then
      if delay > 1 then
        temp_bus1 <= i_bus1 & temp_bus1(delay*bus_size - 1 downto (delay-1)*bus_size);
        temp_bus2 <= i_bus2 & temp_bus2(delay*bus_size - 1 downto (delay-1)*bus_size);
      else
        temp_bus1 <= i_bus1;
        temp_bus2 <= i_bus2;
      end if; 
    elsif (RISING_EDGE(i_Clock)) then
      
      o_bus1 <= temp_bus1(bus_size - 1 downto 0);
      o_bus2 <= temp_bus2(bus_size - 1 downto 0);      

    end if; -- reset + rising_edge(clk)

  end process logic;


-------------------------------------------------------

end a;
```